# Is it possible to define custom keyboard shortcuts for the ipython interactive shell?

Tags: python, ide, ipython

I'd like to bind magic commands that I have created to shortcuts, is there anyway that this is possible in the ipython shell (not the notebook)? On the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/custommagics.html) for magic commands, there doesn't seem to be any discussion of whether you can create shortcuts for your own magic commands.

Comment: Did you see this page: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/custommagics.html

Comment: I did, I don't think they mention anything about keybindings, my original question was probably unclear since I know how to define my own magic commands, I just can't bind them to anything.